# NativeScript Floating Button

Tags: telerik, nativescript

I just recently started with NativeScript and ran into a roadblock.

I have a AppBuilder/NativeScript project (iOS only for now) in which I want to implement a floating action button.  I have seen plenty of examples where the FAB is positioned above a ListView however my scenario is different:

- I have 3 repeaters (displaying unrelated data).
- each repeater may or may not be visible on the page (if there is no data to display, I am hiding it)
- I would like to place the FAB on the bottom right regardless of what the content is
- The whole page is wrapped in a ScrollView

I tried using nativescript-floatingactionbutton, but I cannot compile with this module installed.  I keep getting *"Cannot build project because module nativescript-floatingactionbutton contains insecure code. Remove the module and try again."*

I also tried an AbsoluteLayout on the page level, but it seems that the layout overlays the rest of the page and I cannot even see the content, just the FAB.

Here is the markup

```html
<Page id="MainPage" xmlns="http://schema.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" actionBarHidden="true" loaded="pageLoaded" xmlns:drawer="nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer" xmlns:sharedDrawers="widgets/drawers">

  <drawer:RadSideDrawer id="mainDrawer">

    <drawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>
      <ScrollView id="wrapper" opacity="0">
          <DockLayout stretchLastChild="false">
            <GridLayout id="mainHeader" cssClass="header" dock="top" columns="50, *, 50">
              <Label class="icomoon-icon" text="&#xe6d0;" row="0" col="0" horizontalAlignment="center" tap="openDrawer" fontSize="18" />
              <Label horizontalAlignment="center" text="{{ pageTitle }}" row="0" col="1" />
              <Label class="icomoon-icon" text="&#xe610;" row="0" col="2" horizontalAlignment="center" tap="notifications" fontSize="18" />
            </GridLayout>

            <GridLayout cssClass="main" rows="auto, *" >
              <StackLayout row="0">
                <StackLayout  cssClass="{{arr.length ? '' : 'hidden' }}">
                  <label cssClass="section-title" text="{{strings.activeLoans}}"></label>
                  <Repeater items="{{ arr }}" >
                    <Repeater.itemTemplate cssClass="item">
                      ...
                    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                  </Repeater>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout cssClass="{{arr2.length ? '' : 'hidden' }}">
                  <label cssClass="section-title" text="{{strings.history}}" marginTop="20" />

                  <Repeater items="{{ arr2 }}">
                    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                      ...
                    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                  </Repeater>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout cssClass="{{arr3.length ? '' : 'hidden' }}">
                  <label cssClass="section-title" text="{{strings.data}}" marginTop="20" />
                  <Image src="~/images/pic.jpg" />

                  <Repeater items="{{ arr3 }}">
                    <Repeater.itemTemplate>
                      ...
                    </Repeater.itemTemplate>
                  </Repeater>
                </StackLayout>
              </StackLayout>
            </GridLayout>
          </DockLayout>
        
      </ScrollView>
    </drawer:RadSideDrawer.mainContent>

    <drawer:SideDrawer.drawerContent>
      <sharedDrawers:mainDrawer />
    </drawer:SideDrawer.drawerContent>
  </drawer:RadSideDrawer>

  <!--<AbsoluteLayout cssClass="fabContainer">
    <Image src="res://fab_add" tap="newLoan" cssClass="fab" />
  </AbsoluteLayout>-->
</Page>
```

I have truncated and changed some of the non-relevant code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi @dpdragnev - I actually created the FAB plugin. It's not that it contains insecure code but AppBuilder requires plugin authors be white listed by Telerik. This has come up before and I've been white-listed but the system hasn't been updated. I was told the next AppBuilder release I'll be white listed as an author so my plugins should work soon (think this month). As for the positioning, you should add your markup here so everyone can get an idea of what you want. You likely need to use `AbsoluteLayout` for that, but Grid and Dock also might work.

Comment: Hi Brad,  Thank you for your response.  Your plugin is exactly what I needed, but the AppBuilder for some reason does not like it.  There was an update for the AppBuilder that I ran today, but I still get this message.  You should probably follow up with them to make sure they have while-listed you.

Comment: I will edit my answer with the markup

Comment: Hi @dpdragnev, I tested `nativescript-floatingactionbutton` pluging in AppBuilder app and it looks that it is working properly with `tns-core-modules --version 2.0.1` and `nativescript-floatingactionbutton --vertion 2.2.4`. You could review this article http://docs.telerik.com/platform/appbuilder/nativescript/working-with-custom-modules/manage-telerik-verified-plugins#add-plugins  and verify, whether you are using latest version for both plugins.I tested the plugin with given example in npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-floatingactionbutton

Comment: This is strange.  I have tns version 2.0.0 (it would not let me update to 2.0.1) and nativescript-floatingactionbutton --vertion 2.2.4 however I still get Error: Cannot build project because module nativescript-floatingactionbutton contains insecure code. Remove the module and try again.  @NikolayTsonev, did you test it on iOS or Android.  I am testing on iOS actual device.

Comment: @NikolayTsonev,  I upgraded to tns-core-modules to 2.0.1 and I am still getting the same error.  I am using Telerik Platform Business Edition 2016.2.609.1.
I noticed that the nativescript-floatingactionbutton module is not available in the Plugin Marketplace tab.  I had to go to the NPM tab to install it.  Not sure if this is important or not.

Comment: Hi @dpdragnev, I have tested my app only on Android, however today I review my project ones again and tried to build the project on iOS and got the same issue with the same notification. In regard to that I am still looking for a solution and I will write you back when i found some possible solution.

Comment: Thank you @NikolayTsonev

Comment: @BradMartin `scroll view > stack view > list view` in this structure how can i implement FAB ? I Tried putting after `scroll view > stack view > FAB` but it does not stay above list view instead it scrolls with page.

Comment: Check the README on the repo: https://github.com/bradmartin/nativescript-floatingactionbutton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аs Brad Martin says, the plugin cannot be built inside `Telerik Platform` as not all of its maintainers are white listed. To be more precise, when an iOS build of a plugin containing a pod file is initiated in `Telerik Platform`, the service checks its maintainers. As a pod file can contain post build scripts, `Telerik Platform` is currently flagging plugins as safe by keeping a list of white listed maintainers.

This plugin has 5 maintainers - Brad Martin being only one of them. Brad’s email is white listed but ‘gabrielbiga’ and ‘lazaromenezes’ are not yet whitelisted. @Brad Martin- can you please let us know whether we should whitelist these users emails as well? 
The other approach would be to replace the pod file with frameworks instead.

One last thing, moving forward with `Telerik Platform` releases `Telerik Platform` team will be working on improving the support for plugins containing pods. They will probably remove the "whitelisting” approach with sandboxing instead but we couldn’t yet comment on any specifics.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  It appears that I will have to find another way to implement the floating button.  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: As a temporary solution I would suggest you to use `GridLayout` and normal NativeScript Button. You could style the Button to look like `Floating Button` using `border-radius` or `clip-path` and to attached animation to it. I am attaching a link with my sample project, where you could review my suggestion https://github.com/tsonevn/FloatingButton.git

Comment: Thank you @NikolayTsonev